# Regex match first number if it does not appear at the end

Tags: sql, regex, teradata

I am currently facing a Regex problem which apparently I cannot find an answer to.
My Regex is embedded in a teradata SQL of the form:

`REGEXP_SUBSTR(column, 'regex_pattern')`

I want to find the first appearance of any number except if it appears at the end of the string.

For Example:

*"YEL2X30" -> "2"*

*"YEL19XYZ05" -> "19"*

*"YELLOW05" -> ""*

I tried it with `'[0-9]+(?!$)/'` but this returns me a blank String always.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shot in the dark here since I'm unfamiliar with teradata and the supported SQL-functionality. However, reading the docs on the [`REGEXP_SUBSTR()`](https://docs.teradata.com/r/756LNiPSFdY%7E4JcCCcR5Cw/GawwvSb00HmeuOgDwXHNdA) function it seems like you may want to use the 3rd and 4th possible argument along with a slightly different regular expression:

```
[0-9]+(?![0-9]|$)
```

Meaning: 1+ Digits that are not followed by either the end of the string or another digit.

I'd believe the following syntax may work now to retrieve the **1st** appearance of any number from the matching results:

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR(column, '[0-9]+(?![0-9]|$)', 1, 1)
```

The 3rd parameter states from which position in the source-string we need to start searching whereas the 4th will return the 1st match from any possible multiple matches (is how I read the docs). For example: `abc123def456ghi789` whould return `123`.

---

Fiddling around in online IDE's gave me that:

```
CREATE TABLE TBL (TST varchar(100));
INSERT INTO TBL values ('YEL2X30'), ('YEL19XYZ05'), ('YELLOW05'), ('abc123def456ghi789');
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(TST, '[0-9]+(?![0-9]|$)', 1, 1) as 'RESULTS' FROM TBL;
```

Resulted in:

```
RESULTS
2
19
NULL
123
```

***NOTE:*** I also noticed that leaving out the 3rd and 4th parameter made no difference since they will default back to 1 without explicitly mentioning them. I tested this over [here](https://paiza.io/projects/9QWSmSr00LWkMsUR_ZSoDw?language=mysql).

Comment: Nice regex, can be shortened using character classes: `'\d+(?!\d|$)'`

Comment: @dnoeth. Thank you. I tried that as my initial answer but fiddling online it gave me false positives as though `\d` wouldn't be supported. Not sure why, so I switched to the explicit number-range.

Comment: Teradata RegExes are based on PCRE, don't know for MySQL. I like RegEx101 for testing: https://regex101.com/r/9TvKMq/1

Comment: Both solutions work perfectly with teradata and my dataset. Thanks to the both of you! I will be taking one of those solutions as they look the cleanest so far.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly the simplest way is to look for digits followed by a non-digit.  Then keep all the digits:

```
regexp_substr(regexp_substr(column, '[0-9]+[^0-9]'), '[0-9]+')
```

Comment: Thanks, works out perfectly for my use case! I thought about something like this myself but could not quite figure it out. Using regexp_substr two times does the trick though! Probably going to take one of the solutions below just because it looks a bit cleaner.